# How To Convert A className Into An ID in jQuery

Tags: jquery

In my example I have a basic tabbed content setup. The buttons have classes that match the divs IDs. onClick, I'd like to grab the className, and find an ID with the same name

[image]

**jQuery:**

```
$("li").click(function() {
   var liClass = this.className;
   $("li").removeClass("active");
   $("#"+liClass).addClass("active"); 
});
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/CSS_Apprentice/kpo7t6xh/

Comment: It's not clear to me what the issue is.

Comment: I'll try to edit my question afterward, but currently my jQuery doesn't work. I want to 1) take the class name of the li that is clicked 2) convert that name into an ID name (example: .one becomes #one) and 3) add a class to that ID

Comment: That's what you're doing. But you're removing the `active` class from the list item, which doesn't have it--but you'll have another issue as well in that you'll need to remove `active` from all the divs. In your current code that won't be an issue; an answer below addresses this.

Comment: did you include your jquery framwork in your script?

Comment: No, I forgot add add the jQuery library when I made my example :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's wrong:

```
 $("li").removeClass("active");
```

Should be:

```
 $("div").removeClass("active");
```

The `.active class was on the divs not the lis.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/2nf7h6pe/1/)

Comment: Ahh this makes me happy and sad at the same time, haha! Glad I had the code right, can't believe I overlooked that :P thanks so much!

Comment: No prob happens to me often :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use some prefix to match you classes and id

```
$("li").click(function() {
     var target_class = "";
            var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
            for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
                  var matches = /^prefix_(.+)/.exec(classList[i]);
                  if (matches != null) {
                    var fxclass = matches[1];
                    target_class = "prefix_"+fxclass+"";
                  }
            }
       $("li").removeClass("active");
       $("div").removeClass("active");
       $("#"+target_class ).addClass("active"); 
});
```

Comment: Good heavens. That seems far more complicated than necessary.

Comment: No, this could be helpful to someone else

Comment: @CSSApprentice Honestly, I don't see how. It's looping when you could just do `hasClass`, and I can't think of why it'd need to be done like this anyway.

Comment: @DaveNewton the `hasClass` cannot get the class with just prefix. It has the limitation of using `hasClass`

Comment: @user2352577L There's nothing unknown in the OP's original question; you added an additional step. I wouldn't do it the way the OP is either, but... this all just seems unnecessary. Just my opinion; YMMV.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Not sure the best way to go about it (new thread/chat/etc/), but I'd like to hear how you'd do it. This was just the simplest way that made sense to me, but I'm still fairly new to jQuery.

Comment: @CSSApprentice Well, the accepted answer seems simpler.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Ah, okay. Thanks anyways!